# C++ function template: Derived and explicit return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following problem that I just don't see a proper solution to (and maybe there is none): I have a templated method where the return type is dependent on the input type, and thanks to C++11 `decltype` the return type can be derive easily, *but* I would also like to allow the user to define the return type explicitly if desired.

More formally I have a templated function `f`, that I would like to be callable as `f(x)`, with neither input nor return type explicitly defined. And I would also like to be able to call it as `f<ret_t>x()` with the return type explicitly defined, but the input type still derived automatically.

Now, satisfying the first constraint with C++11 is easy (let's assume there's another templated method :

```
template<typename InT>
auto f(const InT& in) -> decltype(/* code deriving the return type using in */);
```

But this will not allow overriding of the return type, for that I would have to add it as a second template parameter and move the `decltype` derivation into the template definition and probably need to use `std::declval<InT>` or `std::result_of`:

```
template<
    typename InT,
    typename RetT = /* code deriving return type using InT and declval/result_of */>
RetT f(const InT& in);
```

However, this way I always need to also explicitly define `InT` when calling `f`. So the declaration of `f` in order to be able to leave `InT` open but specify `RetT` should be:

```
template<
    typename RetT = /* code deriving return type using InT and declval/result_of */,
    typename InT>
RetT f(const InT& in);
```

But since at the point where I need to specify a default value for `RetT`, `InT` is not yet available and hence cannot be used.

The best workaround I could come up with so far, which is not very satisfying and doesn't seem to work anyway since deduction of `RetT` fails (apparently due to the fact that you cannot deduce the types from default arguments), is:

```
template<typename RetT, typename InT>
RetT f(
    const InT& in,
    const RetT& = std::declval</* code deriving return type using InT or in and declval/result_of */>());
```

Are there any better ways to have a default value for `RetT` that is dependent on `InT` while still being able to explicitly specify `RetT` if desired? It's important to note that the return type needs to be available in the function implementation in order for the object of `RetT` to be allocated directly and only once inside the method body.

Comment: The last line is broken in two ways: you can't odr-use `declval` and you can't deduce from a default argument.

Comment: @Niall: Yes, `result_of` would probably work. But the issue is about the order of arguments in that case.

Comment: @T.C.: Now that you mention it, yes you cannot deduce from a default argument. I will mention this.

Comment: Just write two overloads: `template <typename IntT> f(InT) -> decltype(...)` and `template <typename R, typename InT> R f(InT)`

Comment: @K-ballo Compiler will generate ambiguous call errors if `R == InT`.

Comment: @Constructor: No, it won't, not if done properly. The standard library does this, in `std::bind` for instance.

Comment: @K-ballo That's only because you rarely have a functor returning something of its own type. Given `struct foo { foo operator()() const { return *this; } };`, `std::bind<foo>(foo());` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `std::conditional` and a `dummy` type to check if the function has automatic deduced type or user selected type.

If the user explicitly selects a return type, the return type will be something different from the `dummy` type and this will be the return type of the function. Otherwise just use the deduced type as before.

Following one example of usage:

```
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct dummy
{
};

template<typename RetType = dummy, typename T>
auto f(const T& in)
-> typename std::conditional<std::is_same<RetType, dummy>::value, T, RetType>::type
{
    std::cout<<typeid(RetType).name()<<" "<<typeid(T).name()<<std::endl;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    f(1);
    f<float>(1);
}
```

Comment: Probably don't even need to use `dummy` - `void` is likely sufficient.

Comment: @T.C. If the users selects void as the return type, the automatic deduced type will be used. I don't think this is desired

Comment: A default template argument before the non-defaulted ones... I did not know this. This is cool.

Comment: @Felics It doesn't make much sense to select `void` as the return type especially given the "the object of `RetT` to be allocated directly and only once inside the method body" in the question.

Comment: @T.C. yes, this is true. And also if the function returns any object void is not a valid return type.

Comment: @Felics: Thanks, this works nicely and I guess as elegant as it gets.

Comment: WOW.. I thought it would be impossible >o<